# Scheme - how to convert let* expression to an application expression

Tags: scheme

I want to convert this expression:

```
(define x 2)
(define y 5)
(let*
     ( (x 3)
       (f (lambda (z) (* x y z)))
       )
  (f x))
```

to an equivalent application expression without using `let*`. Thank you!

Comment: `let*` is equivalent to nested `let`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: Note that `(define x 2)` is ignored by this code, because you're declaring `x` locally within the `let*` and it shadows the global variable.

Comment: Sounds like a good exercise. Let us know how it goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
((lambda (x y)
  ((lambda (x)
    ((lambda (f) (f x))
     (lambda (z) (* x y z))))
   3))
 2 5)
```